# Parallel Execution: How to update Excel WorkBook using Synchronized method, only after synchronized method execution is completed?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I have written a non-static synchronized method in a class to avoid multiple threads updating the Excel Workbook at the same time. For example Thread with ID #9 and #10 are trying to update Excel, expected is that Thread#9 should complete the operation of synchronized method and then Thread#10 should be able to invoke the method which is not happening for us. Below is the code snippet.

```
public synchronized boolean put(String parameterName, String parameterValue) {
    try {
        System.out.println("Start Time:= " + Thread.currentThread().getId() + " :: " + LocalDateTime.now().toString());
        updateData(data.get("XLFileName"), data.get("XLSheetName"), parameterName, parameterValue, data.get("TestCaseID"), data.get("Iteration"));
        System.out.println("End Time:= " + Thread.currentThread().getId() + " :: " + LocalDateTime.now().toString());
        return true;
    } catch (FilloException flex) {
        flex.printStackTrace();
        // extentTest.log(LogStatus.FATAL, "A", flex.getMessage());
        return false;
    }
}

public void updateData(String XLFileName, String XLSheet, String parameterName, String parameterValue, String testCaseID, String iteration) throws FilloException {
    Fillo fillo = new Fillo();
    Connection connection = fillo.getConnection(XLFileName);
    String strQuery = "Update " + XLSheet + " Set " + parameterName + "='" + parameterValue + "' where TestCaseID = '" + testCaseID + "' and Iteration = '" + iteration + "'";
    connection.executeUpdate(strQuery);
    connection.close();

    try {
        Thread.sleep(10000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

```
Current Output:

Start Time:= 10 :: 2017-03-20T15:03:31.041
1 row(s) affected
Start Time:= 9 :: 2017-03-20T15:03:31.619
1 row(s) affected
End Time:= 10 :: 2017-03-20T15:03:41.201
End Time:= 9 :: 2017-03-20T15:03:41.675
```

```
Expected Output:

Start Time:= 10 :: 2017-03-20T15:03:31.041
1 row(s) affected
End Time:= 10 :: 2017-03-20T15:03:41.201
Start Time:= 9 :: 2017-03-20T15:03:31.619
1 row(s) affected
End Time:= 9 :: 2017-03-20T15:03:41.675
```

Tried with synchronized block as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try with Synchronized block with lock on class as shown below.

```
public synchronized boolean put(String parameterName, String parameterValue) {
    synchronized (DataBook.class) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Start Time:= " + Thread.currentThread().getId() + " :: " + LocalDateTime.now().toString());
            updateData(data.get("XLFileName"), data.get("XLSheetName"), parameterName, parameterValue, data.get("TestCaseID"), data.get("Iteration"));
            System.out.println("End Time:= " + Thread.currentThread().getId() + " :: "  + LocalDateTime.now().toString());
            return true;

        } catch (FilloException flex) {
            flex.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi..I am facing same issue so was browsing through web and landed here. What is DataBook class here? Is it a predefined class or custom class? where should these both methods reside? in main class?

Answer (score 0):

Since this is not static, the lock used here is an [intrinsic lock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html), i.e. a lock per object. What it means is that you have a lock per thread, so each thread has the right to execute its own `put` method, thus the output you observe.

What I would suggest to obtain the desired output is to make this method static, so that the lock is associated to the class, and only one Thread will be able to access it at a time, giving you the expected output (or almost, thread 9 could start sooner than Thread 10):

```
public static synchronized boolean put(String parameterName, String parameterValue)
```